# Check if product is downloadable in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have edited some templates for my WooCommerce shop. I have removed the default price because I use the plugin [WooCommerce Extra Product Options](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-extra-product-options/7908619?ref=nvomedia) for enabling the price and control some specific options.

Now, I want to add downloadable products to my shop. The plugin doesn't support downloads because there is not enough API for that, the author says.

So, I want the price back in my template but only for products where 'download' is turned on. How can I check if a product is downloadable via themplates? Otherwise, all the downloadable products are placed int he category 'Downloads', so a check if the product is in that category is also good for me.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **is_downloadable()** function of WP.
**WC_Product::is_downloadable()** – Checks if a product is downloadable or not.

```
$bool = WC_Product::is_downloadable();
```

It is located in

> File name: woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php

```
 public function is_downloadable() {
 return $this->downloadable == 'yes' ? true : false;
 }
```

Just call this on product-page template.

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
global $post, $woocommerce, $product;
 if ($product->is_downloadable('yes')) {
    // Your Logic.
}else{
    // Your Logic.
}
?>
```

For more details [See the Link.](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productis_downloadable/) and [another link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-icon-if-product-is-virtual-or-downloadable)

Answer (score 3):

You can check it through **is_downloadable** function. Add it anywhere in your **product-page template**.

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
global $post, $woocommerce, $product;

if ($product->is_downloadable('yes')) {
    // Your Logic.
}else{
    // Your Logic.
}
?>
```